Webpack not tree shaking unused import
Webpack is not treeshaking this unused import when creating a production build in my next.js app.
I have marked sideEffects: false in @shared/graphql.mock package.json
file:
import { MockData } from '@shared/graphql.mock'

const should = (
  fn,
) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    return fn
  }
}

/*#__PURE__*/ const mockData = should(() => MockData)()

webpack output:
const should = (fn)=>{
    if (false) {}
};

/*#__PURE__*/ const mockData = should(() => _shared_graphql_mock_DATA__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.N[0])();

Added example repo here: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/turborepo-template-forked-qzgpmn?file=%2Fapps%2Fweb%2F.next%2Fserver%2Fpages%2Fapi%2Ftest.js%3A81%2C1-95%2C1&welcome=true
See:
packages/server/server.ts
apps/web/pages/api/test.ts
Output:
apps/web/.next/server/pages/api/test.js

_shared_graphql_mock_DATA__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is it ? that looks like the whole module instead of any specific function. how could it even run

@TusharShahi not sure I understand, it is a JSON object containing mock data

The annotation for the terser should be place before the statement to mark the function call as side effect free.
const mockData = /*#__PURE__*/ should(() => _shared_graphql_mock_DATA__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.N[0])();

The reason for webpack not dropping unused functions in your build is because the minimize option is disabled. You have to enable webpack to use the terser plugin.
Refer to the unused option in the compression options section for the minimizer that facilitates this.
In next.config.js,
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  transpilePackages: ["ui"],
  webpack: (config) => {
    // config.optimization.minimize = false;
    return config;
  },
};


I tried that, also did not work

I cannot reproduce the issue when the annotation is before the function call, but it reproduces when I have it at the beginning of the statement. My version is Next.js v14.2.5. Also I'm not setting the 'sideEffects' option in package.json

Thanks, I have added an example repo - still cannot get it to exclude the mockdata from the final bundle

I took a look in the repo and the minimize option is disabled in your webpack configuration. What is the reason for that?

Disabled it so that I can inspect the bundle easily, could that cause an issue?

Yes, that disables the minimizer as well. You can configure the TerserPlugin for the minimizer if you want to keep variable names unmangled.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
